# Where does the tool txt2pdf.exe store its configuration settings?

Tags: pdf

I am using txt2pdf to convert text files to pdfs. It's been working great but I got a new PC and I can't get it to retain the settings for lines per page. I don't see any contact information on their web site.

https://www.sanface.com/txt2pdf.html

Does anyone know where older program s might store their data?

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: Ah yes. Windows 10. I should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 0):

I found it using a system file watcher:
C:\Users[user]\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Windows\win.ini

Comment: There should be a backslash after the C:\Users but I can't figure out how to put it there =)